# Something is wrong with my code

Tags: c#, object, exception, enums

I am making a music maker program in C# (visual studio).
Here is my code:

```
int accCount = 0;
enum accidental { flat, sharp, none }
accidental thisAcc = accidental.none;
if (keyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Length < 8)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please select a key!");
}
else switch (keyComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
{
    case "C major - A minor":
        accCount = 0; thisAcc = accidental.none;
        break;
    case "G major - E minor":
        accCount = 1; thisAcc = accidental.sharp;
        break;
    ...etc..
}
```

and so on...
This all is included in `postButton_click(postButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
But when I click the button, an exception is shown 
(An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Program.exe)
And if I select "break", this line is selected:

```
object key(int count, accidental ac) (here is the cursor){ 
    return key(0, accidental.none); 
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Sorry if this question is not specific enough, just tell me.

Comment: Your function is calling itself. It's named key, and you're calling it within itself. You have no termination case, so it just keeps calling itself. That creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Your code does not compile - you've got a mix of type definitions and executable code, all of which cannot be in a method.  Based on your snippit, it looks like you're calling `key()` from within itself, which would result in a stack overflow unless you have some sort of breaking condition.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to learn about and start following .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well yes, look at this code (reformatted from your question for readability):

```
object key(int count, accidental ac)
{ 
    return key(0, accidental.none);
}
```

That will just invoke the same method... which will invoke the same method... which will invoke the same method etc, until it runs out of stack space.

It's not clear what you *intended* to return from this method, but you need to stop recursing in this infinite way.

Comment: Oh thank you, I never did this before - I only need to declare this object and assign it later, but if I don't declare a body, I get this error:   "'Program.UIForm.key(int, Program.UIForm.accidental)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial."   What should I do with this?

Comment: Oh, I answered myself. I actually thought an object can store two variables.   I made two single variables (one int and one accidental).

Answer (score 4):

A stackoverflow means that you have some unbound recursion in your application.  In English this essentially means you're calling a method again and again.

Can you see how you're calling your method `key` within itself?

Comment: "Can you see how you're calling your method within itself?" -- Why don't you point it out instead.

Comment: There's a difference between encouraging self help and forcing someone to scour their code needlessly when all you have to do is point it out to them.  Why not reword it ""Can you see how you're calling your method <insert method here> within itself?"

Comment: For the sake of argument I've modified it

Comment: In fact -- and this is probably just because I'm not on my game today -- I couldn't even locate the recursion until you just edited your answer.

Comment: FWIW, making a programmer go back through their code is never needless where debugging is concerned. Especially seeing as a second glance usually fixes the issue. Also, he gave him a direction to run instead of handing him code, which constitutes a good answer to me. +1